# Is there a way to utilize simple math operations for color correction?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, shaders, color

For me the currently available (2.79) color modifiers have limited capabilities.

[image]

To modify a HDR image which has RGB values beyond 0-1 (0-45 for eg.) I really miss an *offset* function which is basically adds or substracts values.

To write a pyhton script for color correction can't be very complicated I guess. I saw that there is a script node but according to the documentation it is only for plug OSL shading nodes and it is only for Cycle Renderer.

So is there a way to utilize simple math operations like +, -, /, * for color correction? Is it possible to create a color correction node without coding in C or C++?

Comment: The CDL works here, as does the Mix node's Add, Subtract, Multiply, and Divide. A fulcrum based contrast is a trivial divide by fulcrum, power, then multiply, for example. Also remember, "HDR" has little meaning unless referring to a display class or a file format. Scene referred values are an entire model, and not governed by ranges of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the *Converter > Separate RGB* and *Converter > Combine RGB* nodes to get access to each channel.

You get 3 streams of float values, on which you can do *Converter > Math* operations.

When you have build you node network, you can pack it into a Group node (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) and reuse this node in other projects (append or link from a library .blend or save the node to start-up .blend)